# Github Actions - Where do I upload the Certificates and provisioning profiles

Tags: ios, git, github, certificate, github-actions

I am implementing github actions in my project for Build, test and Deploy.
While Building the app, it gives me an error,

```
"Code Signing Error: No profile for team 'XXXX' matching 'XXXX' found"

Xcode couldn't find any provisioning profiles matching 'XXXX/XXXX'. Install the profile (by dragging and dropping it onto Xcode's dock item) or select a different one in the Signing & Capabilities tab of the target editor.
```

Tried to build the project with distribution certificates.

I have tried to upload the certificates and provisioning profiles on a different repository in my account, but it doesn't work.

Where do we upload the certificates?

Comment: @matt How will the project get build on repository, if it doesnt have certificates?

Comment: Clues on how to do this: https://github.com/Apple-Actions/import-codesign-certs

Answer (score -2):

Hi As per your question it's seem that you are trying to implement CI/CD in your project. You can integrate fastlane that will take care of uploading certificates on a git repo. It will upload all your certificates and provisioning profile on git repo and help's to fetch on your device's keychain.